# No DHCPOFFERS received

Tags: linux, networking, modem

Modem: Huawei ME906s-158, 
Computer: Raspberry Pi

I am getting this error message

```
No DHCPOFFERS received
```

Am I missing a step?

Running *usb-devices* shows:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=04 Cnt=04 Dev#=  6 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=ff MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  3
P:  Vendor=12d1 ProdID=15c1 Rev=01.02
S:  Manufacturer=HUAWEI Mobile
S:  Product=HUAWEI Mobile
S:  SerialNumber=0123456789ABCDEF
C:  #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 3 Atr=a0 MxPwr=2mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=02(commc) Sub=0e Prot=00 Driver=cdc_mbim
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 1 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=02 Driver=cdc_mbim
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=06 Prot=14 Driver=option
```

Running *ip addr* shows

```
5: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1460 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4a:f3:aa:36:b1:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I connect using *minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0*

```
AT^NDISDUP=1,1,"apn"
OK
AT^NDISSTATQRY?
^NDISSTATQRY: 1,,,"IPV4"
```

Running *dhclient -v wwan0* shows

```
Listening on LPF/wwan0/4a:f3:aa:36:b1:34
Sending on   LPF/wwan0/4a:f3:aa:36:b1:34
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPREQUEST on wwan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPREQUEST on wwan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPDISCOVER on wwan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
......
DHCPDISCOVER on wwan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
No DHCPOFFERS received.
Trying recorded lease 100.xxx.xx.x
PING 100.xxx.xx.x (100.xxx.xx.x) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 100.xxx.xx.x ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

bound: renewal in 227191 seconds.
```

Comment: IF you reboot the modem, do you get an IP address?

Comment: No, I cannot get an IP address.  Once the modem is power off & on, it will default to Configuration 2 which uses a cdc_ether driver.  Changing to Configuration 3 will use cdc_mbim.

Comment: Do you connect something to the modem after rebooting it, but before connecting the Linux machine?

Comment: I do not quite understand the question.  I will try to answer as best as I can, the modem is disconnected  from the Linux computer after powering it off.  Then I reconnect it to the computer again.  Even if I can get the IP before, it will be gone when the modem reboots because the Configuration is reset to 2.